# datatable load large data c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

in my c# mvc 4 application project, we need to fetch the data from the sqlquery then filling into C# datatable.
We have to fill datatable with over 5 million rows and 12 columns.

if the data has been <1 million the application takes 3 minutes.
if it is >1 million system getting hanged.

This is code I am using.

```
public DataTable GetTheData()
    {
        DataTable dtDataTablesList = new DataTable();
        string NewconnectionString ="Mycooectionstring";
        SqlConnection spContentConn = new SqlConnection(NewconnectionString);
        string sqlselectQuery = "select * from table";
        try
        {
            spContentConn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlselectQuery, spContentConn);
            sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            adptr.Fill(dtDataTablesList);
            spContentConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (spContentConn != null)
                spContentConn.Dispose();
        }
        return dtDataTablesList;
    }
```

Comment: What are you going to do with 1M records? You can't show them anywhere. Processing them is what the database is for. A web application will never run faster that a well written query with proper indexes. What are you trying to do?

Comment: BTW you should use a `using` block instead of this `try/finally` with the extraneous `catch` that simply breaks the call stack.

Comment: I had a situation when I needed to read in a large table (50 million rows) and then write to another database with bulk upload. So this really does have a usage.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you require even 10 lakhs of record to show at a time. You should use pagination and limit number of record. I suggest if you have that much large record to show then you should show at most 500 record at a time. Even 500 records is large so you can decrease no. of record by discussing with your team and client.

Even if you managed to load all those record in considerable amount of time browser will not able to handle that much of record and may crash. But this is only my assumption not tested and verified.

You can refer following SQL code for pagination

```
create table #TestTable(
 PK int primary key,
 Name nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #TestTable (PK, Name) values
(1, 'Name1'),
(4, 'Name4'),
(6, 'Name6')

select * from
(
 select row_number() over(ORDER BY pk ) SN, * from #TestTable
) temp
where SN>=1 and SN<=500
```

1 and 500 should be dynamic. In page 1 you pass 1 and 500 in page 2 you should pass 501 and 1000.